# Stopping a scroll at a certain div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to stop div from scrolling after reaching a certain point on a page, and for some reason I can't get it to work.

This is what it shows when I scroll all the way to the bottom of the footer, but I want it to stop after reaching the end of a section div

The div around the whole section is:

```
content
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPZ6p.png)

My jQuery:

```
   jQuery(function($) {
        var $el = $('#scroll'),
        top = $el.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (pos > top && !$el.hasClass('fixed')) {
          $el.addClass('fixed');
        } else if (pos < top && $el.hasClass('fixed')) {
            $el.removeClass('fixed');
        }

    });

    });
```

My CSS:

```
#scroll.fixed {
            position: fixed;
            top: 20%;
        }

        #scroll {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
        }
```

I tried

`stopPosition = $('.content').offset().top;`

But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

In this example the scrolling will stop when you reach the div inside the **.wrap**
you must get the position of that div and and set the window to that position each time you scroll down that div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var stopScroll = $('.wrap > div:nth-child(2)').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.wrap div:nth-child(2)').offset().top) {
      $(window).scrollTop(stopScroll); /*this will stop the scroll to not go further down*/
    }

  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #252525;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}

.wrap {
  padding-top: 74px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-1,
.block-2 {
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin-top: 185px;
}

.block-1 {
  background: #27AACC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block-2 {
  background: #668E99;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block-1">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-1">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```